# GridBagLayout components not aligning

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I've recently been working with the layout manager `GridBagLayout` and have been running into trouble when it comes to the grid system it uses.

What I want to do is have the JButton I create here:

```
    JButton myButton = new JButton("Some text");

    gc.gridx = 2;
    gc.gridy = 4;
    gc.weightx = 0.5;
    gc.weighty = 0.5;

    jp.add(myButton, gc);
```

To be 2 columns over, and 4 rows down given the code:

`gc.gridx = 2`
`gc.gridy = 4`

I define the number of columns and rows in the component (JPanel) here:

```
GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gc.gridwidth = 2;
    gc.gridheight = 10;
```

However, what I am getting is this:

[image]

The components are overlapping despite being in clearly different sections. Any help is much appreciated. Here is the full code:

```
package com.UI;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class UserInterface{

public static void main(String[] args) {


    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            JFrame f = createFrame();

            JPanel jp = createPanel();

            addLabelAndText(jp);

            f.add(jp, BorderLayout.WEST);

        }

    });



}



static JFrame createFrame() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();

    f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


    f.setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    f.setVisible(true);

    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    return f;
}


static JPanel createPanel() {

    JPanel jp = new JPanel();

    jp.setBackground(Color.gray);

    jp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());


    Dimension size = jp.getPreferredSize();
    size.width = 200;

    jp.setPreferredSize(size);

    jp.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());


    return jp;

}

static void addLabelAndText(JPanel jp) {//How to call a type represented by the passed String? JLabel, for example?

    GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gc.gridwidth = 2;
    gc.gridheight = 10;

    JTextField jtb = new JTextField(5);

    JLabel jl = new JLabel("Enter input here: ");


    gc.gridx = 2;
    gc.gridy = 0;
    gc.weightx = 0.5;
    gc.weighty = 0.5;

    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;


    jp.add(jtb, gc);

    gc.gridx = 1;
    gc.gridy = 2;
    gc.weightx = 0.5;
    gc.weighty = 0.5;

    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END;

    jp.add(jl, gc);

    JButton myButton = new JButton("Some text");

    gc.gridx = 2;
    gc.gridy = 4;
    gc.weightx = 0.5;
    gc.weighty = 0.5;

    jp.add(myButton, gc);


  }


}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: `GridBagLayout` will discard empty columns/rows from its calculations.  If I understand correctly, you will need to put blank components, whose preferred size is greater then `0x0` to generate the spacing

Comment: I see. How would one add blank components? Just new Component()?

Comment: You need to make sure that their `preferredSize` is set, otherwise they will default to `0x0` and you will pretty much end up with the same result

Comment: Because `GridBagLayout` is also not uniform (unlike `GridLayout`), the size of the individual columns/rows is based on the largest component in those columns/rows.  You could also try using the `GridBagConstraints` to introducing padding, which might be better, all-round, solution

Comment: Is there a way to manually set how large each column/row is? Also, the padding Insets worked great. However, will such a solution be long-term reliable?

Comment: Using padding/insets is a better, overall solution, as it's simpler and easier to maintain and you get better overall control

Comment: Thank you MadProgrammer. This has to be like the 50th time you've helped me out. Much appreciated!

Comment: Your code `gc.gridwidth = 2;` is setting the number of grid cells used by all the child components added with that constraints objects. The parent container can deal with any (reasonable) number of cells.

Comment: @Matthew, in the future please post a picture of your frame, not the entire desktop. I can't even see what your frame looks like because it is so small in the context of the entire desktop. Only show use the image directly related to the problem.

Comment: @camickr got it, will do :)